# E-Sword and PlayonLinux

Tags: launcher, playonlinux, application-switcher

I have a weird question. I do have E-Sword bible app on PlayonLinux. It works great. The thing is, E-Sword will only open when I open PlayonLinux first. I will have to use PlayonLinux and then open E-Sword.

I do have Adobe in PlayonLinux but Adobe apps will may be in launcher and I may open only Adobe with Wine; however, E-Sword won't do this. Any way to fix this ?

Understand ?

Comment: open E-Sword in terminal using something like `wine E-Sword.exe` and post what error it shows.

Comment: The E-Sword itself has [gold status](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1341). So it should work great on Wine. You have to open PlayOnLinux, select E-Sword and click *Create a shortcut* in the left *Actions* pane. Then use this shortcut from desktop.

Comment: here is what it says. ...I have used Synaptic and everything is supposed to be fix tho. Terminal says that "it looks like wine32 is missing, you should install it".......terminal also says that "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."...............BUT Synaptic says I have no issue.

Comment: This is not an answer for your specific question - but have you run the following command `apt-cache search bible`? There are lots of Bible applications for Linux, some of which are already in your default repositories. It might be worth seeing if any of them suit your particular needs.